# How I can find sql query for execution plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, profiling, sql-execution-plan

Some programm generate and send queries to sql server(on high load production).  I want take plan of concrete query of concrete table. I start profiler with "Showplan XML" and set filter on TextData(like %MyTable%) and DatabaseName. It show rows with xml in TextData that describe execution plans(for all queries of my table). But I know that exist 5 different sql queries for this table.

How I can match some concrete query with correspond plan without use statistic?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but [here is a post on how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/6167855) and of course you can query any plan currently in the plan cache.

Comment: Yes I can use STATISTICS PROFILE(from this article), but I am afraid of bad perfomance. Is it problem?

Comment: You are running a trace via SQL Profiler... that's a performance concern in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason this has to be done on the production environment? Most really bad execution plans (missing indexes causing table scans etc.) will be obvious enough on a dev environment where you can use all the diagnostics you want.

Otherwise running the SQL on the query cache (as in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan?noredirect=1&lq=1) someone else mentioned) will probably have the lowest impact as it just queries a system table rather than adding diagnostics to every query.